# Using "opened up " as adjective

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, adjectives, grammaticality-in-context, conversation

I heard the following in a movie
"I want you to open up a little bit"

Can I say instead "I want you to be opened up "

Comment: No, you cannot use a phrasal verb as an adjective (as far as I know). You can say "I want you to be (more) open".

Comment: 'To be opened up' sounds as though you were talking about a surgical operation!